# How to select Option element in Select list by id of an option not value?

Tags: jquery, html

I have select html element with 'options' have both 'value' and 'id' values.
What I want is to select the 'option' which has specific 'id' not 'value'.
How can I do this using jquery?

**Update:**
Thanx for your answers.
Here's my select list:

```
<select style="width:102%" id="appStatusSelect">
    <option value="#3366CC" id="0">color1</option>
    <option value="orange" id="1">color2</option>
</select>
```

I want to select the option with id=1 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

```
$('option[id="yourid"]');
```

Comment: but you shouldn't use multiple selectors when selecting by `id` because as an id is supposed to be unique, `$("#id")` is sufficient enough. Adding more elements to your selector will make your code less readable and slower (event if jquery is smart enough to avoid this slowness)

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, then all you are looking for is this:

```
var yourOption = $("#optionId");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#<id of your element>")
```

what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something along this line?

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$("#mySelect option:selected").length)
    $("#mySelect option[value='3']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
</script>
```